# Spaces between columns in Twitter boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I create columns like on attached image? I don't know how to set space between all columns. Please any hint.

[image]

Comment: You should have add necessary code so people can try to help. No one will give you ready made code mate.

Comment: you can customize gap between 2 columns. For that try this http://getbootstrap.com/customize/.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a margin to you columns. To have 4 columns, you'd start with a div with the class="row" then inside of that a div with the class=col-md-3 (or whichever size you want the 4 columns across), and give that div a margin-right of however many px's you want. Your final column (the 4th one in the row) probably should not have the margin-right if your design has the columns centered on the page. Bootstrap automatically gives columns 15px on either side. If you need to look up more information about how it works, the space between columns is called the "gutter" so you could search "gutter width" for example to find different ways of working with it.